# How to add "ALL" as label and totalItems as value in paginationPageSizes select box as adding like [25, 50, 75] in UI-grid using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to add a option like ALL which will display all records in the UI-grid using angularjs, like below

```
paginationPageSizes: [
  {label: "10", value: "10"},
  {label: "25", value: "25"},
  {label: "All", value: $scope.gridOptions.totalItems}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust their optionsdropdown but its not totally smooth. I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqOlmtn1rWCCYpZizyXu?p=preview) showcasing a possible solution.

First you modify the paginationPageSizes object the way you already did

```
paginationPageSizes: [
  {label: '25', value: 25},
  {label: '50', value: 50},
],
```

To add your `ALL`, you can push that value after getting your data.

```
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
.success(function (data) {
  $scope.gridOptions1.data = data;
  $scope.gridOptions1.paginationPageSizes.push({label: 'ALL', value: $scope.gridOptions1.data.length});
});
```

Now comes the tricky part!

You have to modify the options-template to match your new paginationPageSizes object.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/pagination',
  "<div class=\"ui-grid-pager-panel\" ui-grid-pager ng-show=\"grid.options.enablePaginationControls\"><div class=\"ui-grid-pager-container\"><div class=\"ui-grid-pager-control\"><button type=\"button\" ng-click=\"paginationApi.seek(1)\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageBackward()\"><div class=\"first-triangle\"><div class=\"first-bar\"></div></div></button> <button type=\"button\" ng-click=\"paginationApi.previousPage()\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageBackward()\"><div class=\"first-triangle prev-triangle\"></div></button> <input type=\"number\" ng-model=\"grid.options.paginationCurrentPage\" min=\"1\" max=\"{{ paginationApi.getTotalPages() }}\" required> <span class=\"ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number\" ng-show=\"paginationApi.getTotalPages() > 0\">/ {{ paginationApi.getTotalPages() }}</span> <button type=\"button\" ng-click=\"paginationApi.nextPage()\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageForward()\"><div class=\"last-triangle next-triangle\"></div></button> <button type=\"button\" ng-click=\"paginationApi.seek(paginationApi.getTotalPages())\" ng-disabled=\"cantPageToLast()\"><div class=\"last-triangle\"><div class=\"last-bar\"></div></div></button></div><div class=\"ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker\">"+

  "<select ng-model=\"grid.options.paginationPageSize\""+

  //"ng-init=\"grid.options.paginationPageSize = grid.options.paginationPageSizes[0]\" " +

  "ng-options=\"o.value as o.label for o in grid.options.paginationPageSizes track by o.label\">"+

  "</select><span class=\"ui-grid-pager-row-count-label\">&nbsp;{{sizesLabel}}</span></div></div><div class=\"ui-grid-pager-count-container\"><div class=\"ui-grid-pager-count\"><span ng-show=\"grid.options.totalItems > 0\">{{showingLow}} - {{showingHigh}} {{paginationOf}} {{grid.options.totalItems}} {{totalItemsLabel}}</span></div></div></div>"
);
```

See 4th line where I added the new parse logic.

Now regarding the not easily solved problem. As you can see in the Plunkr, you dont have a default selection this way, because you got an object instead of plain values.

The `ng-init` block shows what could be done about that but you would need to dig very deep into their sourcecode because the paginationPageSize is used as a plain number in their code and instead we have an object now.

Update: I tried a few setups and it actually worked. Using the options without track by made the difference. See [updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lqOlmtn1rWCCYpZizyXu?p=preview).

```
"ng-init=\"grid.options.paginationPageSize = grid.options.paginationPageSizes[0].value\" " +

"ng-options=\"o.value as o.label for o in grid.options.paginationPageSizes\">"+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't find a way to select the default value in select box of pagination Page Size, which may create issue. This is the place where i got stuck. If we change the ng-model of grid.options.paginationPageSize the whole table get affected. If there is a option in UI-grid for this means it will be awesome.

Comment: I updated the Plunkr and it works fine now. Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: It works correctly as i required. Thanks a lot. Now the table page Length filter looks awesome :-)

Comment: @CMR In your Plunkr code if you set the pageSize 25 to 50, still it displayed the 25, seems to me that it taking first item to default select from the paginationPageSizes array, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Jitendra yep that happens in the template ```ng-init=\"grid.options.paginationPageSize = grid.options.paginationPageSizes[0].value\"```. You can adjust that at will.

Comment: @CMR Thanks, I will give a try.